# VLC EPG only shown for current program

Tags: vlc-media-player

I watch terrestrial television (DVB-T2) with VLC player. I put information about all available stations in an `.xspf` file like

```
    <track>
        <title>Das Erste</title>
        <location>dvb-t://frequency=746000000:bandwidth=8</location>
        <extension application="http://www.videolan.org/vlc/playlist/0">
            <vlc:id>13</vlc:id>
            <vlc:option>dvb-adapter=0</vlc:option>
            <vlc:option>live-caching=300</vlc:option>
            <vlc:option>program=769</vlc:option>
        </extension>
    </track>
```

When I right click on the TV program and select Tools => EPG I only see the program for the selected station. Is it possible to configure VLC that the EPG for all stations of that frequency are shown?

**EDIT 20180809**
When I omit the line `<vlc:option>program=769</vlc:option>` in the `.xspf` file I get like six programs on one frequency. I see the EPG for all six programs. To switch channels I have to right click the video and select some sub menu and finally select the other program I want to switch to.
I'd love to have all programs in the playlist. The EPG for all programs of the current frequency would be a nice plus.